# CSS Conditional does not work in iPhone 6

Tags: css, iphone

On the iPhone 6 my mobile responsive CSS does not extend the full width of the Portait view? This seems to be the case on the home page and all underlying pages? I’d like for this to utilize the entire screen given the small screen.

Screenshots and links below.

I've tried different dimensions using the following CSS at 375px for example like this with no luck:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px)
.site-container {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Screenshot on iPhone 6: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmzbmnh77j7twtu/2015-10-12%2018.53.04.png?dl=0

URL example of the actual website (view in portrait on iphone please), Bitly used to avoid Google indexing.

http://bit.ly/1IUoDbn

Comment: You have an element in your page bigger than the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of facebook share/like widget and its text (its width too big, bigger than container width). Try to delete text, for example, or edit it to be shorter, and everything will be fine.